# how to pass string type list in F# function

Tags: f#

This code is giving error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type    'string' but here has type ''a * 'b'

```
open System 
open System.Linq

let list1 = [ "one"; "two"; "three" ]
let list2 = [ "one"; "two"; "three" ]

let tablesValidation (l1 : string list) (l2 : string list) =
    printfn "%O" l1
    printfn "%O" l2


tablesValidation(list1,list2)
Console.ReadKey() |> ignore
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In F#, function arguments do not need parentheses and are separated by spaces. Change it to this:

```
tablesValidation list1 list2
```

Your original version passed a tuple value as a single parameter, hence the error message, where `a * b` means a tuple with two fields.

Comment: One more question @Chad Gibert what is the alternative of Expect of linq in f# ?

Comment: If you're talking about emulating `Except` in Linq, you may want to try F#'s [`Seq.filter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/seq.filter%5b't%5d-function-%5bfsharp%5d)

Comment: Yes, exactly I am trying the same :)

Comment: For example, if I want to apply the same in my above mention code then how could I?

Comment: You could define a custom `except` function like this: `let except a b = let set = Set b in Seq.filter (not << set.Contains) a`